# swift 3 phone call using special character #

Tags: ios, swift3, phone-call

I have problem using # in phone call,  in the console it shows `(tel://*155*222222*123%23)`, I believe the problem is using #. I have look it up and some people said its not allowed to use special character in tel.

```
var code = String()
var ID = String()
var Card = String()
@IBAction func ChargePhone(_ sender: Any) {
    ID = "123"
    ID = ID.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    Card = "222222"
    code = "*155*"


        var RESULT = "\(code)\(Card)*\(ID)#"

        RESULT = RESULT.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(RESULT)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Phone app does not allow special characters on phone number redirection on iOS.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html